# Python using JSON Payload - String indices must be Integers

Tags: python, json, lambda

Hi I am having some issues deserializing json in my lambda, from looking online it looks like the problem is I have a string and trying to get a key value as if it was a dict, but still not sure on the correct solution.

Here is the code that gives the error

```
def handler(event, context):

    try:
        json_str = json.dumps(event)
        request_json = json.loads(json_str)
        req = request_json['body']
        logger.info("req : " + str(req))
        if req:
            key = req['executionArn']
```

This line gives the issue -

```
key = req['executionArn']
```

The logger line gives me this

```
req : {"executionArn":"123"}
```

I execute a post request on the lambda using this as a payload through api gateway

```
{"executionArn":"123"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `event` variable which you convert to a string with `dumps`, then you convert it back to JSON with `loads`, then you try to access a property of that JSON. Is that correct?

Double conversion aside, `request_json['body']` is a string and if you know it's JSON, you can load it just like you did before:

`req = json.loads(request_json['body'])`

Comment: That worked thanks! So I actually can leave the dumps and loads out at the start as it is already json?

Comment: If you know it's already JSON (a dictionary, actually) then yes, you can access `event['body']`, but I don't know what you're getting into `event` so I cannot be sure.